# Why is $\{p \in \mathbb{Q},:p<1\} | \{p \in \mathbb{Q}: p \geq 1\}$ a real number?

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers, rational-numbers

A basic example of a Dedekind cut is:

$A|B$ = $\{p \in \mathbb{Q}:p<1\} | \{p \in \mathbb{Q}: p \geq 1\}$

This is very confusing because what we have here is a pair of subsets of $\mathbb{Q}$ whereas (without knowing Dedekind cut) we are used to real number as being a singleton

For example, $1$ is a real number. We can think of $1$ as a singleton all by itself i.e $\{1\} \in \mathbb{R}$

- Is there any reconciliation between between singleton in $\mathbb{R}$
  point of view and a Dedekind cut which is a pair of subsets of
  $\mathbb{Q}$ in defining a real number?
- Since $\{p \in \mathbb{Q}: p<1\} | \{p \in \mathbb{Q}: p \geq 1\}$ is
  a real number, which real number does it represent?
- Since $\{p \in \mathbb{Q}: p<c\} | \{p \in \mathbb{Q}: p \geq c\}$ is
  a real number, for some rational number $c \in \mathbb{Q}$, then why
  isn't K-12 taught using addition and multiplication of $\{p \in
     \mathbb{Q}: p<c\} | \{p \in \mathbb{Q}: p \geq c\}$ instead of $a,b
     \in \mathbb{R}$, since they are equivalent

Note: first time seeing Dedekind cut as ways to represent real numbers

Comment: The point is that there is a bijection between the singletons and Dedekind's cuts (this bijection is the reconciliation you ask for). The cut in the second item represents the real number 1. Actually, when you use Dedekind's cuts you only need to keep one of the two sets (for instance you keep only ${p<c}$) and identify this with a real number (its supremum).

Comment: Any two complete ordered fields are isomorphic.  But how do you know there is any complete ordered field at all?  The "Dedekind Cut" construction is a construction of a complete ordered field.  There are others as well.  But these are only for advanced math students.  Of course K-12 does not do this method.  Indeed, unless you specialize in mathematics, you may never see this construction at all.

Comment: A real number is not a singleton. A singleton is a set of one element. A real element is one object, it is not a set of one object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can identify a rational number $c \in \mathbb{Q}$ with its Dedekind cut

$$\{x \in \mathbb{Q}, \,x < c\}|\{x \in \mathbb{Q}, \,x \ge c\}$$

Of course, it might seem we've just introduced a fancy way to obfuscate the really simple notion of rational numbers. But the point of Dedekind is that there are Dedekind cuts that are **not** associated with a rational number, such as

$$\{x \in \mathbb{Q}, \,x^2 < 2\}|\{x \in \mathbb{Q}, \,x^2 \ge 2\}$$

This cut cannot correspond to any rational number $c$ because this number should satisfy $c^2 = 2$. So Dedekind cuts **extend** rational numbers. We can also see define operations (comparison, addition, multiplication, inversion) that extend those of rational numbers. So we can think of those cuts as lying on a number line, and we can prove this line has no "holes".

In summary, Dedekind cuts are a **construction** of the real numbers : this a set that has all the properties of the real numbers, namely :

- we can add, subtract, multiply, divide real numbers (more precisely $\mathbb{R}$ is a field)
- numbers lie on a line without holes (which means there's a total ordering, compatible with sums and products, and each set that has a majorant has a supremum)
- all these operations ($+,-,\times,/, \le$) extend those on $\mathbb{Q}$

The goal of this construction is to prove that such a set (real numbers and its properties) exists. Once the proof is done, you're free to get back thinking about them as numbers on a line.

Answer (score 5):

The whole point of Dedekind cuts is to prove that there exists a complete, ordered field with $\mathbb{Q}$ (isomorphic to) a subfield. Once we have that field, we rename it $\mathbb{R}$ and identify* each of the cuts with a real number. So if you prefer, you can think of the elements of $\mathbb{R}$ as a collection of sets, but this is rarely useful.

As far as your second question, the cut whose lower set is $\{q \in \mathbb{Q} : q < 1\}$ gets identified with its supremum, $1$.

As far as why we don't teach this in K-12, just think about why we don't teach children addition from the perspective of ordinals and successor functions. Without a degree of mathematical maturity, it's too abstract to be useful. Or for a different analogy, why don't we teach children to read with Shakespeare?

---

*identify == bijection

Comment: Thanks, the notes I am using defines real number right off of the bat as dedekind cuts and offered no alternative definition to real numbers which kind of threw me off having never seen cuts before, it was like my whole life was a lie